# How to update TextView in onReceive method in widget provider

Tags: android, android-widget

Source:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    String s = "MusicPlayer";
    if (MusicPlayerActivity.currentActivity != null) {
        s = MusicPlayerActivity.currentActivity.getCurrentTrackName();
    } else {
        Log.d(MusicPlayerActivity.TAG,"STARTING ACTIVITY FROM WIDGET");
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MusicPlayerActivity.class);
        intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent1);
    }
    // I WANT TO UPDATE TEXT VIEW HERE
    if (MusicPlayerActivity.currentActivity != null)
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_NEXT)) {
            MusicPlayerActivity.currentActivity.playNext();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_PLAY)) {
            MusicPlayerActivity.currentActivity.playPause();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_PREV)) {
            MusicPlayerActivity.currentActivity.playPrevious();
        }
}
```

I tried something with this code:

```
Log.d(MusicPlayerActivity.TAG,s);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.w_trackInfo, s);
appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds, R.id.w_trackInfo);
```

But this doesn't work if I place it in comment position. Any help appreciated.

Comment: just make remoteViews to public static and then try to set anywhere

Comment: Nope, that did not work either, it seems that it needs to be committed into widget somehow.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found solution just add this on comment place:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget_layout);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.w_trackInfo, s);
    AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(
            new ComponentName(context, MusicWidgetProvider.class),views);
```

Comment: This one worked. :D

And this is the best solution I have found so far. Thanks :)

Comment: @Dejan You For best solution

Comment: Tried different solutions myself & searched for solutions through stackoverflow and other sites. None worked except this one!

Comment: This won't work if there are multiple instances of the same app widget. As in my case unfortunately